# How to force Chrome debugger to automatically go to the currently debugged line?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

As I F10 or F11 through my javascript code in Chrome Dev Tools, sometime the execution will move to a line that is not currently in the view (same file though).

How do I tell Chrome to bring that line of code into the view?

Comment: Did you try double-clicking on the top line in the Call Stack?

Answer (score 0):

As you step through the code you should be able to open the call stack panel to the right of the sources window and double click on the breakpoint you wish to jump to.